# Cannot connect to Binance websocket. I get: WebSocketBadStatusException: Handshake status 400 Bad Request

Tags: python, api, websocket, binance

I am trying to connect to the Binance websocket stream.
Following [their documentation](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/futures/en/#websocket-market-streams) I use the below code to establish the connection:

```
from websocket import create_connection

ws = create_connection('wss://fstream.binance.com/')
```

When running it though, I get the following error:

```
WebSocketBadStatusException: Handshake status 400 Bad Request
```

I could not find any info on the web about this error.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 10):

This Point is somewhat unclear in the Binance API-Docs.

The base urls for the futures are:

- wss://fstream.binance.com
- wss://fstream3.binance.com

But if you just connect to these base urls you get the mentioned exception.
You should complement the url-strings to

- wss://fstream.binance.com/ws
- wss://fstream3.binance.com/ws

This is the same for spot markets and all the other websockets. Always put a "/ws" at the end.

You could also start subscribing with the connection-url then it looks like this spot-market example:

- wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@aggTrade

(But i think connecting just with "/ws" and then live subscribing/unsubscribing as explained in the docs to streams is the better way.)

Comment: There does seem to be an issue with subscribing: https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/issues/14

Answer (score 6):

I gotta say it took me a long time to figure the solution out but here it goes.

Binance API documentation should be edited because it is missing the port for the fstream.binance.com

The port is 443.

So you should use

"fstream.binance.com:443" instead of

"fstream.binance.com".

Hope it helps. (Hell yeah it does!)

Comment: thanks a lot, @Omid, it took me a long time as well to debug, was getting connection timed out for sooo long. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad it finally got connected.

Answer (score 0):

You could install python-binance and use the BinanceSocketManager

python -m pip install python-binance

Use the following code I found [here](https://livedataframe.com/live-cryptocurrency-data-python-tutorial/)

```
import time
from binance.client import Client # Import the Binance Client
from binance.websockets import BinanceSocketManager # Import the Binance Socket Manager

# Although fine for tutorial purposes, your API Keys should never be placed directly in the script like below. 
# You should use a config file (cfg or yaml) to store them and reference when needed.
PUBLIC = '<YOUR-PUBLIC-KEY>'
SECRET = '<YOUR-SECRET-KEY>'

# Instantiate a Client 
client = Client(api_key=PUBLIC, api_secret=SECRET)

# Instantiate a BinanceSocketManager, passing in the client that you instantiated
bm = BinanceSocketManager(client)

# This is our callback function. For now, it just prints messages as they come.
def handle_message(msg):
    print(msg)

# Start trade socket with 'ETHBTC' and use handle_message to.. handle the message.
conn_key = bm.start_trade_socket('ETHBTC', handle_message)
# then start the socket manager
bm.start()

# let some data flow..
time.sleep(10)

# stop the socket manager
bm.stop_socket(conn_key)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the path on websocket connect!

Take a look to the binance api docs:
https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/futures/en/#websocket-market-streams

python-binance does not support websocket to binance futures endpoints, so you can use unicorn-binance-websocket-api instead, here is an example for future endpoints:
https://github.com/oliver-zehentleitner/unicorn-binance-websocket-api/blob/master/example_binance_futures.py